# Two minuses make a plus

Tags: terminology, cliche

As English is not my native language, I have a trouble to find the correct way to express the following:

*Two negations are equivalent to an affirmation*

properly.

This is how it translates from my native language (Greek) if it is translated word by word: "δύο αρνήσεις ισοδυναμούν με μία κατάφαση", and it does not sound good to me.

Is there a standard English expression (an appropriate cliché, for example) with this meaning?

UPDATE. Let me give an example of what this expression really means:

"There is NO student in this classroom who DOES NOT HAVE a pencil."

is logically equivalent to:

"Every student is this classroom HAS a pencil"

So the first sentence has two negations - a negation of a negation - while the second one has affirmative nature.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right, but three lefts do.

Comment: Two Wrights make an airplane.

Comment: Every student has at least ONE pencil

Comment: Grammatically, your example sentence makes sense, but stylistically I was taught to avoid it because it can lead to awkward constructions. Instead, either state things in the positive (as in your second example), or use a word that expresses the negative, eg, No student lacks a pencil.

Comment: It would help for you to provide more context about how you want to use this expression. English teachers give students a common admonition: "Don't use double negatives!"  If you're a math teacher you could make a joke that math is better than english because you can use double negatives all you want - as long as you can keep it straight that what you're saying is what you think you're saying and what others think your saying is what you're really saying.

Comment: Not not is is. (joking)

Answer (score 5):

Two negatives make a positive. Minus times minus is plus. Also, [two wrongs (don't) make a right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_wrongs_make_a_right).

**Edit** to address your update: the term in logic for the situation you describe is [*double negation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation). Not to be confused with the *linguistic* term [*double negative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative), where two (or more) negatives might or might not resolve to a positive, depending on language and context.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right, but three lefts do. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

'Two minuses make a plus'. That's how it was explained to me, over fifty years ago!

Comment: I corrected the title of my question: minus-> minuses.